# Regex that matches contents of () with nested () in it

Tags: regex, bash, pcre

I have a messy text file(Due to nature of the contents I cannot paste it).

In the file I want to match things that are in unnested parenthesis.

Here is sample that includes the problem:

```
a(b()c((d)e)f()g)h(i)
```

The output that I need is:

```
(b()c((d)e)f()g)(i)
```

(basically everything in the largest parenthesis, less 'a' and 'h')

Again I cannot post the actual contents but above example illustrates the problem I have in original file.

I am working on this from bash, I am familiar with sed, grep, but not awk unfortunately.
Thanks

Comment: So you want the substring from the first opening parenthesis to the last closing paranthesis? If so, ordinary string functions would appear to be more suitable.

Comment: @AndrewMorton can you elaborate. I'm open to non-regex solutions

Comment: Will there be cases like `ab(cd)ef(gh)ij` if so, would you want `(cd)(gh)`?

Comment: Why did you tag `pcre`?

Comment: @anubhava because that that is the kind of regex that I can use, rather than js ones

Comment: There is no pcre in BASH tools, unless you want `perl` solution.

Comment: @smerny I didn't think about that, but given the size of my file I guess so, I updated question to include that

Comment: @anubhava It doesn't matter to me is can just do grep -P or grep -E

Comment: @anubhava my bottom line is that I have access to remote computer and the shell that I got there is BASH

Comment: Your question was little vague earlier but your latest edit made it worse. How is `everything in the largest parenthesis` including `(i)` also in output?

Comment: @anubhava, I believe the OP was referring specifically to the original example, and in THAT example it happened to be that everything within the outer parens was everything within any parens.

Comment: Right I know and that output made sense. But look at the latest edit where expected output includes string outside largest parenthesis also.

Comment: @smerny you are right

Comment: @anubhava this is why I wrote "largest/unnested"

Comment: @sgp667, you should remove the "largest parenthesis" wording now as it is not necessarily the case. Anyway, regex isn't really made to handle arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: @smerny just for future reference what would you use for that then?

Comment: Typically it would be done by keeping track of how many open parens there were minus the close parens you come across... gathering up the contents as long as you have opens that haven't been closed.. or something like that... but apparently pcre supports balancing groups as demonstrated in @thatotherguy's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since regex will find the longest possible match, you can just use

```
\(.*\)
```

If you care about nesting and want to find the outermost, e.g. for `((a)) and (b))))` you want to find `((a))` and `(b)`, then that's a typical example of a grammar that you technically can't match with regular expressions.

However, since you tagged your post PCRE:

```
grep -P -o '(?xs)(?(DEFINE) (?<c>([^()]|(?&p))) (?<p>\((?&c)*\)))((?&p))'
```

Comment: What if input is `a(p)(b()c((d)e)f()g)h'`

Comment: @anubhava, that's really a question for OP

Comment: Absolutely cannot work with your input of `a(b()c((d)e)f()g)h(i)` where you want `(b()c((d)e)f()g)(i)` in output. This regex will give you `(b()c((d)e)f()g)h(i)` with `h` also.

Comment: I cannot claim to understand everything in new regex but I am sure it would be working fine, but OP's requirements have changed off late and I am a bit confused what he really wants as output.

Comment: @thatotherguy, that is pretty slick... https://www.debuggex.com/r/1wVmrMp99nBmbpUt

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I know there is a good answer, but posting the one I came up with to enrich the range of ides. ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/jU9dQ9)).

```
(?x)
(?(DEFINE)(?<nest>(\((?:[^()]*(?1)?[^()]*)\))))
\((?:[^()]*(?&nest)?[^()]*)*\)
```

Of course it needs to be flattened onto the `grep` line.